Is there a one-to-one relationship other than the T-duality between the winding number and the momentum along the compactified dimension?
I have a doubt related to compactifying a dimension leading to the concept of string winding.
Suppose we compactify a dimension, the momentum along this dimension makes the string move along this dimension. If this momentum is positive, it means that the string is going forward in this dimension and thus it means that the string is propagating along the compactified dimension. This compactified dimension is periodic, so the string's momentum would make it move in a periodic (or circular) direction. So if the momentum runs for sufficient time the string would move along the compactified dimension and thus would wrap around it at least once (because the momentum makes the string move in this dimension).
Thus my question is that is there a one-to-one relationship other than the T-duality between the winding number and the momentum along the compactified dimension? It looks like the greater the momentum, the more number of times the string would get wrapped around.
